# How do I combine a Combo Box with a Tree in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, tree

For my application, I want a [Combo Box](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) that displays its elements when dropped down as a [Tree](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html).  Problem is, I'm not versed well enough in Swing to know how to go about doing this.  At least without ending up writing a new widget from scratch, or something to that effect.

How would I do something like this without creating one from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I would implement this as a JTree component in a JViewPort, followed by an expansion button.  When collapsed, it would look like a combo box.  When you click the expansion button, the viewport would expand, allowing you to scroll and select a node in the JTree.  When you selected the node, the view port would collapse back to only show the selected node and the expansion button.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of work, but I suppose that'll do.  I'll just have to play around with it.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, guess what! This is your lucky day.

I've used this framework in the past. It is very complete. I didn't know they have this 
already.

[JIDE Soft](http://www.jidesoft.com/)

[alt text http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/8324/combotreejj1.png](http://img89.imageshack.us/img89/8324/combotreejj1.png)

Is not too expensive, but it will take you some time to understand the API ( it is not that is complex, but they've created a LOT of new stuff )

Comment: Cool, but I'm not sure I'd be willing to pay for something that I'm only gonna use a tiny bit of.  Thanks for the find, though.

Comment: Yeap. I agree. Then suggestion of show/hide a panel with the jtree will do. I'm pretty sure that's how they did that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Override the getListCellRendererComponent methode and create the components in level order.
For every tree level move the painted string 3 spaces to right.

Example:

1

.   a

.   b

2

.   c

The original implementation you can look from

```
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                                       JList list,
                                       Object value,
                                       int index,
                                       boolean isSelected,
                                       boolean cellHasFocus) {
        //Get the selected index. (The index param isn't
        //always valid, so just use the value.)
        int selectedIndex = ((Integer)value).intValue();

    if (isSelected) {
        setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
        setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
    } else {
        setBackground(list.getBackground());
        setForeground(list.getForeground());
    }

    //Set the icon and text.  If icon was null, say so.
    ImageIcon icon = images[selectedIndex];
    String pet = petStrings[selectedIndex];
    setIcon(icon);
    if (icon != null) {
        setText(pet);
        setFont(list.getFont());
    } else {
        setUhOhText(pet + " (no image available)",
                    list.getFont());
    }

    return this;
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't that lose the expand collapse behavior

Comment: You could have changed a bit the code you found from the [Java Tutorial on ComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) to match your explanation...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ComboBoxEditor whose component ( returned by getEditorComponent )  is a JTree

Although you may have already tried that.

I don't know how would it look like. Post an screenshot if you make it work. :)

**EDIT**

I give it a quick dirty try. Its awful, but is a start.

[alt text http://img120.imageshack.us/img120/2563/yiakxk2.png](http://img120.imageshack.us/img120/2563/yiakxk2.png)

Here's the code, for what is worth. :(

Probably you should start thinking in alternatives. What about a fake Combo that is a JButton without border when pushed a hidden panel will appear  with the tree displayed.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ComboTree {
    public static void main( String [] args ) { 
        JComboBox c = new JComboBox( new String [] { "Hello", "there"});
        c.setModel( new CustomComboModel() );
        c.setEditor( new TreeComboEditor() );
        c.setRenderer( new TreeComboEditor() );
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add( c , BorderLayout.NORTH ) ;
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );

    }
}

class CustomComboModel implements ComboBoxModel {
     public Object  getSelectedItem() { return ":P"; }
     public void    setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {}
     public void    addListDataListener(ListDataListener l) {}
     public Object  getElementAt(int index)  { return "at " + index ; }
     public int getSize()  { return 2; }
     public void    removeListDataListener(ListDataListener l)  {}
}
class TreeComboEditor implements ComboBoxEditor, ListCellRenderer {

     // Editor interface
     public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {}
     public Component   getEditorComponent() {
         return new JTree() ;
         }
     public Object  getItem() { return "";}
     public void    removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {}
     public void    selectAll() {}
     public void    setItem(Object anObject) {}

     // Render interface
     public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                                           Object value,
                                           int index,
                                           boolean isSelected,
                                           boolean cellHasFocus) {
        return new JTree();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's just what I was thinking, but I'm not sure how it would handle folding/unfolding vs. selecting an element.  I'll give it a shot soon.

Comment: Don't do it. Looks terrible. :S

Comment: This is absolutely useless code. It doesn't do what is required and it do it it worst possible way. (-1)